# Can't find the place to add in image caption

Tags: 7, media

I installed [image caption](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_caption) module and enable 'Image caption filter' under Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats.

But I can't the place to add in the image caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_caption) is somehow missleading and most of the info there is for D6 version. But at the bottom, it clearly states:

```
jQuery caption
  Less module code
  No configuration needed
  Better javascript captioning logic
```

You can also refer to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1136816) for more info.

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: I know, the info I posted is for Drupal 7.

Comment: Do you mean it only appear if add caption class in source code? There is no a input text to automatically add in the caption?

Comment: Yes it looks that way. It seems that the module was not completely ported from D6, or... maybe this was an intended simplification.